# Solving a linear system of the form C .* (BX) = AX

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, matrix-equations, hadamard-product

I have formed the above problem, which involves a mix between element-wise (Hadamard) multiplication (indicated by ".*") and ordinary matrix multiplication. In this problem I know all of A, B and C but I still have no idea how to solve for X.

Dimensions, if this helps:

- A = N x N (sparse)
- B = N x N (sparse)
- C = N x 1 (not sparse)
- X = N x 1 (not sparse)

The sparse matrices above are populated only with either 0 (of course), +1, or -1.

Alternatively, the problem can also be stated in the form:

log(C) + log(BX) = log(AX)

In a simpler form of the problem, A and B were so sparse that they had only one entry (+1) per row. I found (clumsily) that I was able to go like this:

log(C) + B * log(X) = A * log(X)

... which is easy enough to solve, and gave the correct solution (I am just doing some modelling, so can check against whatever X I use). However, in the "real" problem, my clumsy attempt to pull A and B outside the log operator does not work out.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about solving this problem? It seems I need either

- Some fancy method to combine Hadamard and ordinary matrix multiplication
- Some fancy method to express the logarithm of ordinary matrix multiplication
- Something else I have no idea about (likely)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hadamard product of two vectors is the same as the matrix product of one vector with the diagonal matrix of the other vector. Namely
$$
C.*(BX) = D_CBX
$$
where
$$
D_C = \begin{bmatrix}
c_1&0&\dots&0\\
0&c_2&&\vdots\\
\vdots&&\ddots&0\\
0&\dots&0&c_N
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the equation reduces to
$$(D_CB-A)X = 0$$

Comment: Thanks for this, exactly what I needed. Now, I just have to figure out how to pull a useful solution out of the null space...