# Solving XAY = B for both X and Y

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a problem where A and B are known in the above expression, and I'd like to solve for X and Y concurrently.

Dimensions:

- X is a diagonal matrix (N x N)
- A is square (N x N), and sparse if that helps
- Y is a vector (N x 1)
- B is a vector (N x 1)

For reference, this follows on from my question from yesterday ([Solving a linear system of the form C .* (BX) = AX](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4010446/solving-a-linear-system-of-the-form-c-bx-ax)) which was solved, but unfortunately requires wading through "null space". I was not able to find the desired solution robustly using standard optimization approaches, which has led me to reformulate the problem as above (giving me, unfortunately, two unknowns to solve for).

Many thanks (again) in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution.
$$\begin{split}XAY&=B\\
\left(\begin{matrix}\frac 1 {x_1} & 0&... & 0\\0&\frac 1 {x_2}&...&0\\...&...&...&0\\0&0&0&\frac 1 {x_N}\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}A_1^T\\...\\A_N^T\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}Y_1\\...\\Y_N\end{matrix}\right)&=\left(\begin{matrix}B_1\\...\\B_N\end{matrix}\right)\text { write the matrix}\\
\left(\begin{matrix}A_1^T\\...\\A_N^T\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}Y_1\\...\\Y_N\end{matrix}\right)&=\left(\begin{matrix}x_1 & 0&... & 0\\0&x_2&...&0\\...&...&...&0\\0&0&0&x_N\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}B_1\\...\\B_N\end{matrix}\right)\text { left multiply by $X^{-1}$}\\
&=\left(\begin{matrix}B_1x_1\\...\\B_Nx_N\end{matrix}\right)\text { property of diagonal matrices}\\
\left(\begin{matrix}A_1^TY-B_1x_1+0x_2+...+0x_N\\...\\A_N^TY+0x_1+0x_2+...-B_Nx_N\end{matrix}\right)&=0\text { expand left hand side and subtract the right term from both sides}\\
\left(\begin{matrix}A_1^T&-B_1&0&...&0 \\...\\A_N^T&0&0&...&-B_N\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}Y_1\\...\\Y_N\\X_1\\...\\X_N\end{matrix}\right)&=\text { write in matrix form}\\
\left(\begin{matrix}A&-diag(B)\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}Y\\X\end{matrix}\right)&=0\text { write in block matrix form}\end{split}$$

I'm sorry, it seems like this solution requires null space too.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to clarify, is A a square matrix here? It looks like it must be from the last line, but higher up it is rendered as a vector.

Comment: A is always a matrix, the notation $\left(\begin{matrix}A_1^T\\...\\A_N^T\end{matrix}\right)$ stands for $\left(\begin{matrix}-A_1^T-\\...\\-A_N^T-\end{matrix}\right)$ where $A^T$ is a "row" So the final solution has an $n\times 2n$ matrix times a $2n \times 1$ vector = $2n\times 1$ 0 vector

Comment: Ahhhh that makes sense, thank you. Can't wait to see if this works. I don't suppose you have any words of wisdom for finding a useful answer in null space?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that, sorry haha. It looks like you've got n equations and 2n unknowns. Also made a typo in my previous comment, it should be a $n\times 1$ zero-vector

Comment: Sorry, I have just had a chance to explore this... can the solution be right? The dimensionality does not work out, as we have NxN for A and diag(B), but 2Nx1 for the (Y; X) vector.

Comment: A and -diag(B) are ×2, as mentioned above. Imagine placing A side by side with a diagonal matrix containing the negative of B’s values on its diagonals and 0 in the other entries together to form a block matrix. Don't forget the negative sign on the -diag B. Lastly, what you get as the X's in the (Y; X) vector will have to be "recipricoled" to obtain the original X diagonal matrix (see the second equation in the answer).

Comment: $\left(\begin{matrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&...&A_{1N}&-B_1&0&...&0\\A_{21}&A_{22}&...&A_{2N}&0&-B_2&...&0\\...\\A_{N1}&A_{N2}&...&A_{NN}&0&0&...&-B_{N})\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}Y_1\\Y_2\\...\\Y_N\\X_1\\...\\X_N\end{matrix}\right)$ The dimensions work out. I repeat that you should remember to not forget that there's an inverse relationship between the X's in the (Y;X) vector and the original X diag matrix, or neglect the negative signs on the B's. BTW you don't have to but please consider upvoting the answer if you think this was most helpful in solving your problem

Comment: Ahhhh gotcha, thanks. It was a concatenation, not a subtraction. My bad!